# Can EntityUtils.toString() cause a NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Tags: android, android-networking, android-compatibility

I have a setup where I perform my http requests in the `doInBackground()` method of an `AsyncTask` as follows:

```
@Override
protected HttpResponse doInBackground(HttpRequestBase... httpRequests)
{
    HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpClient.execute(HttpUriRequest);
    return httpResponse;
}
```

This `HttpResponse` object is then passed on to the `onPostExecute()` method of my `AsyncTask` to be passed on to a handler (the original caller of the http request) and processed as necessary, as follows:

- checking the response code using `httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()`;
- getting the response content using `EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity())`).

This setup has been working fine on phones running older versions of Android.

Running my app now on Ice Cream Sandwich (Galaxy Nexus) I find that the first few http requests in my app as above work fine but then there is this one http request which consistently throws an exception with a stack trace as follows (trimmed slightly for readability):

> ....
>
> at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:139)
>
> at java.io.InputStreamReader.close(InputStreamReader.java:145)
>
> at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.close(EofSensorInputStream.java:213)
>
> ...
>
> at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:151)
>
> at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1084)
>
> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

I am confused. Does this then mean that the `EntityUtils.toString(HttpEntity)` method is a potential culprit for throwing the new (and ever so annoying) `NetworkOnMainThreadException`? If so, any advice on reworking my setup to make http requests in a separate thread such that the response can be processed on the main thread?

Comment: I have this same problem but it only happens on some phones and only on some requests.. Sometimes EntityUtils.toString works fine.. weird

Comment: Also beware the default charset of `EntityUtils.toString`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642237/what-exactly-returns-entityutils-tostringresponse/43611274#43611274

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try the following: modify your doInBackground function to return the value of the HTTP response.

```
protected String doInBackground(HttpRequestBase... httpRequests)
{
    HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpClient.execute(HttpUriRequest);
    if (httpResponse.getEntity() != null) {
      return EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: That only gives me the message entity of the response. I also need the status line (i.e. `HttpResponse.getStatusLine()`) and potentially the locale of the response too (i.e. `HttpResponse.getLocale()`). I guess I'll have to extract all these properties in the `AsynTask.doInBackground()` method like you suggest and then wrap them in my own `ServerResponse` class to be passed on to the `onPostExecute()` method... unless there's a better way?!

Comment: Yes. You have to do it in that way.

Comment: Are you sure you have to do it like this? Why would those methods be doing networking???

Comment: When the Entity content is consumed (e.g. converted to a string), it is reading bytes from a network buffer. Personally I like to use ResponseHandler and return a result object, but be aware that Android's moving away from the Apache HttpClient (see http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html).