# What exactly returns EntityUtils.toString(response)?

Tags: android, apache, rest, entity

I'm doing my API REST and I saw that in a lot of examples people use `EntityUtils.toString(response)` to get their `response` into a `String` from their `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` methods. Similar to this:

```
HttpGet method = new HttpGet(url);
method.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(method);
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

**PLEASE AVOID ANSWERS THAT SAID TO ME THAT IT GIVES TO ME A STRING**

I know that it returns to me a `String` with the content of an entity (in this case the response) but here is where my doubts come, because I'm not secure about what this `String` returns. I saw it into the official documentation.

> Read the contents of an entity and return it as a String.

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString(org.apache.http.HttpEntity,java.lang.String)

It is the `content-type` what is returned in the `String`?

On the contrary, are the values that I'm getting with my method what are returned in the `String`?

I think it is the second one question but I'm not secure about that. And, in the case it is true, how this values are stored into the `String`? Are they separated by comas or some special character?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `HttpEntity` represents the content of the body of an HTTP response. `EntityUtils.toString(HttpEntity)` interprets that content as a `String` and returns it to you.

If your HTTP response is something like this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 80

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <nested attr="whatever" />
</root>
```

Then the `String` returned by `EntityUtils.toString(HttpEntity)` will simply contain

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <nested attr="whatever" />
</root>
```

Comment: So, the String ignores the header of the HTTP response? Just the values inside?

Comment: @Error404 An HTTP response has a status line, a list of headers, and a body. The content of the `HttpEntity` is just the body of the HTTP response.

Comment: So I suppose that `Content-type` and `Content-Length` are the headers  and `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` the status line, right? I'm sorry but I'm really new at this.

Answer (score 3):

Beware the default charset of `EntityUtils.toString`:

> Get the entity content as a String, using the provided default
> character set if none is found in the entity. If defaultCharset is
> null, the default "[ISO-8859-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048745/what-is-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-iso-8859-1)" is used.

`org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity, "UTF-8");`