# String can not store large CloseableHttpResponse response

Tags: java

I am trying to get JSONObject from following snippet of code.

But since response body is large it can not store results completely.

Final aim is to convert it to jsonobject or store as Json File

```
CloseableHttpResponse apiResponse;
apiResponse = getReorting(authToken);


String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(apiResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(responseString);
```

Comment: what error are you getting to say that it's to large for String to store? Because from my knowledge String can store up to 2,147,483,647 characters

Comment: There is no error but responseString  got truncated.

Comment: count returned characters, if it's less than 2,147,483,647 then increase your heap size times 2, count returned characters if number it's the same as in first count then your error is not about String at all

Comment: Thanks, length of line shows 43,800 (char count without line ending 43,800). But it is not throwing error.
while debugging i see line truncated with .......
 "iso": "2021-12-10T01:52:25-08:00", "timestamp": ...

Comment: welll... that text sounds more like truncated by ide for viewing. Try to print it to console or to file, then check if it's still truncated

Comment: Hi I tried  to create file using string response 
PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("src/test/resources/response.json");
outFile.println(responseString);

but only 32,768 characters were written

Comment: check what EntityUtils.toString does in code

Comment: EntityUtils just returns HTTP Response 


Content-Length: 46906 returned from HTTP Response 
Is it a reason that sting is getting truncated?

Comment: I must disagree with you. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642237/what-exactly-returns-entityutils-tostringresponse?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: thanks I will check

Comment: Tried lot of combinations for entity response but no success.
when converting to string response is getting trucated.
Could you please suggest?

Comment: can you provide code to replicate that request?